# RoR Devise - create related new object after User creation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have been stuck on this problem for way too long now.

Using Devise for the first time, I am trying to combine new user sign up with the automatic joining of a group, based on the existence of an invitation token in the params. (E.g. Email invitation to join a group, so when they follow signup link and complete signup, they are automatically a member of the invited group)

Following tutorials, I have been able to customise the Devise controller, with the User being created successfully when an invitation token exists, however I cannot then use the ID from the new user object to create a group membership - the membership is created successfully, with group_id added, but the user_id always remains nil.

Below is my customised Devise controller, and relevant models:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create

    super do
      newUser = User.create(resource_params)
      token = params[:invite_token]

      if token != nil
        group = Invite.find_by_token(token).group
        newUser.groups.push(group)
        Membership.create(:user_id => newUser.id, :group_id => group.id)
      end
    end

  end

end



class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
  has_many :gifts
  has_many :posts
  has_many :votes
  has_many :invitations, :class_name => 'Invite', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invites, :class_name => 'Invite', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
end


class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  has_many :invites
  has_many :gifts
  has_many :posts
  has_one :user
end
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to successfully create the Membership object, containing both User_id and Group_id, after the User creation?

Thank you all in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `super` will create the user.  Pass a block to the `super` call that accepts the newly created resource/user and create the membership:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do |user|
      token = params[:invite_token]

      if token.present?
        invite = Invite.find_by_token(token)

        if invite.present?
          Membership.create(user_id: user.id, group_id: invite.group.id)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

There's an example of this here: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/#Configuring_controllers